# PUB/SUB can I .connect() before I .bind()?

Tags: zeromq, netmq, nanomsg

I'm using a **`PUB`**/**`SUB`** design and my question is:

Can I **`.bind()`** to a port after another socket has **`.connect()`**-ed to it,
or should I `.bind()` before another socket tries to `.connect()` to the same address?

In other words:

Does the order of `.bind()` and `.connect()` matter?

( I think this question is not specific to `PUB`/`SUB` but is relevant for any design ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A driving principle behind ZMQ is not worrying whether the socket you're trying to connect to is already there or not.  These are details that ZMQ tries to abstract away from you, the developer.  So, no, the order of `bind()` and `connect()` does not matter for any socket type.

I suggest you read [the zmq guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all) if you plan to do extensive work with it, relevant portion [here](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Getting-the-Message-Out):

> Remember that ZeroMQ does asynchronous I/O, i.e., in the background. Say you have two nodes doing this, in this order:
>
> - Subscriber connects to an endpoint and receives and counts messages.
> - Publisher binds to an endpoint and immediately sends 1,000 messages.
>
> Then the subscriber will most likely not receive anything. You'll blink, check that you set a correct filter and try again, and the subscriber will still not receive anything.

... there's an important point to note here, for PUB/SUB - even if you `connect()` first with your subscriber, that connection doesn't *actually* occur until *after* the publisher has `bind()`-ed, so if you attempt to send messages with your publisher without waiting for your subscriber to finish its connection, those messages will never make it to your subscriber.

Comment: tnx exactly what i was looking for

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the unicast transport, `tcp://` and `ipc://` transport-classes are disconnected so the order of `.bind()` and `.connect()` does not matter.

But an `inproc://` transport-class is connected, so there is a need to `.bind()` first and then `.connect()`.

http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Unicast-Transports

Comment: I guess it depends on which wrapper is being used. I tried it with pyzmq [in this gist](https://gist.github.com/FirefoxMetzger/34336c1a35e26407d50118da7304fb85) and the messages get transferred.